# Replace Amazon EC2 SSH hostnames (text file) from terminal output

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have deployed an Amazon EC2 cluster of 3 Ubuntu machines (2 of them make up the cluster and the last one is just a client who submits jobs and manages their storage). I connect to all of them via password-less SSH.

What happens is that every time I restart these machines they get new public hostnames from Amazon which I want to replace in my SSH configuration file located in `~/.ssh/config`

So far, I figured out a way to get their names and hostnames using Amazon CLI with the following command at my local machine (CentOS 7):

`aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicDnsName,Tags]" --output=text | grep -vwE "None"`

This prints something like

```
ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Name    datanode1
ec2-YY-YY-YYY-YYY.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Name    namenode
ec2-ZZ-ZZ-ZZZ-ZZZ.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Name    client
```

i.e. the hostname, a new line, the corresponding name and so on. The IP fields above like XX-XX-XXX-XXX and so on, are basically 4 hyphen separated numbers of 2 or 3 digits. The `grep` command I have simply removes the last useless line. Now I want to find a way to replace these hostnames to the SSH configuration file or maybe regenerate it, which looks like

```
Host namenode
  HostName ec2-YY-YY-YYY-YYY.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem

Host datanode1
  HostName ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem

Host client
  HostName ec2-ZZ-ZZ-ZZZ-ZZZ.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
```

Please note that I don't know how the Amazon CLI command sorts the output. But of course, I can change the order of the machines in my SSH file or maybe it is a good idea to delete it and recreate it.

Comment: Why don't you use elastic IPs which don't change when you restart the machines?

Comment: @helloV Are you sure? Because I found this in their documentation: `To ensure efficient use of Elastic IP addresses, we impose a small hourly charge if an Elastic IP address is not associated with a running instance, or if it is associated with a stopped instance or an unattached network interface. While your instance is running, you are not charged for one Elastic IP address associated with the instance, but you are charged for any additional Elastic IP addresses associated with the instance.` In my case I stop (not restart) the cluster for some hours per day.

Comment: Yes, you get charged $.005/hour. Half a cent an hour per instance when the instances are stopped.

Comment: @helloV I am a student so I want to keep it low-budget for now since I got unexpected charges in my first bill :)

Comment: ok. perfectly valid conern. Your approach is correct. Let me post a solution soon.

Comment: Are there entries other than these 3 hosts in the ssh config file? It is easy to generate the file than to replace the contents.

Comment: @helloV Yes, typically I use more than 3 hosts. I just have 3 here for simplicity.

Comment: @helloV OK, after struggling with Linux commands I have a Bash script that works :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww I disagree. It fits here pretty well since there are over 45000 about Amazon EC2 here (many of them don't involve programming or development at all) and this questions is closely related to that. By the way, isn't bash script programming?

Comment: @mgus - *"many of them don't involve programming or development at all"* - they all should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I finally figured out and it works. This is Bash script you can just save as `.sh` file like `script.sh` and execute. If it can't run simply do `chmod +x script.sh`. I have added comments to clarify what I am doing.

```
#Ask Amazon CLI for your hostnames, remove the last line, replace the "Name\t" with "", combine every 2 consecutive lines and save to a txt file
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicDnsName,Tags]" --output=text | grep -vwE "None" | sed 's/Name\t//g' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' > 'ec2instances.txt';

#Change the following variables based on your cluster
publicKey="mykey.pem";
username="ubuntu";

#Remove any preexisting SSH configuration file
rm config
touch config

while read line
do
    #Read the line, keep the 1st word and save it as the public DNS
    publicDns=$(echo "$line" | cut -d " " -f1);

    #Read the line, keep the 2nd word and save it as the hostname you will be using locally to connect to your Amazon EC2
    instanceHostname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d " " -f2);

    #OK, we are now ready to store to SSH known hosts
    sshEntry="Host $instanceHostname\n";
    sshEntry="$sshEntry HostName $publicDns\n";
    sshEntry="$sshEntry User $username\n";
    sshEntry="$sshEntry IdentityFile ~/.ssh/$publicKey\n";

    #Attach to the EOF, '-e' enables interpretation of backslash escapes
    echo -e "$sshEntry" >> config

#Below is the txt file you will be traversing in the loop
done < ec2instances.txt

#Done
rm ~/.ssh/config
mv config ~/.ssh/config
rm ec2instances.txt
```